# What is the need of the xfile variable

Tags: c, operating-system, system, freebsd

I am new to system programming. I was going through the header file in `file.h` in FreeBSD as I needed it for some code. The thing I don't understand is what is the need of the `xfile` variable and what is the `xf_data` field. In the sockstat code they have used this xf_data field equating it to the socket (`struct socket *`). Moreover I have seen that there are several places where there is a 'x' prefixed data structure. I don't exactly understand the need of these 'x' prefixed variables. For example. in inpcb.h header file there is a inpcb data structure and a xinpcb data structure. Same with tcpcb and the socket data structures.

- file.h (why xfile?): https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/file.h
- in_pcb.h (why xinpcb?) : https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/netinet/in_pcb.h
- socketvar.h (why xsocket?): https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/socketvar.h
- sockstat.c : https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/456928/

In sockstat.c line 673 they have equated `xf_data` in `xfiles` structure with the socket structure. Does this meant that both are the same thing?

Comment: Just a guess, but *x* seems to be used as an abbreviation for *export* and separates the interface specification from the internal data structure - thus allowing the kernel to evolve whilst maintaining a consistent ABI.

Comment: @RichardSmith ABI ? and why do we need to saperate the internal specification from internal data structure? There are inbuilt ways to get the data for these structures from the kernel in a way that we can't change the values inside these structures. So why 'x' ? We anyway do not interact with the original data structure . Its the kernel call that do it for us if we need any data . Right?

Comment: @RichardSmith Also any idea where I can get the concrete answer. No-one seems to be replying on this thread.

Comment: as it was noted x-structs are there so that in-kernel implementation can change in whatever way developers see fit *without* breaking userspace - userspace will still get the very same data in very same way. in order to find out how to use this stuff you can just inspect existing programs using it, like sockstat, fstat or procstat

Comment: @employeeofthemonth "in-kernel implementation can change in whatever way developers see fit without breaking userspace" Kindly elaborate on this. And plz post that as an answer